# GetFiles with spaces in filename

Tags: c#, file-upload, getfiles

I use the following code to take all the files from a directory and search for a specific file:

```
string [] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\uploads");
foreach(string fileName in fileEntries)
    if (fileName.Contains(name))
        PicturePath = fileName;
```

where "name" is a string which I get from DB.

It seems to work to an extend but if my file contains a space in fileName it only takes the first string from fileName which is the first string before the white space, ignoring th rest. How can i take the full fileName (as well as the path to that file accordingly).

For example: I have a file named "ALEXANDRU ALINA.jpg" inside uploads and in name i have the string "ALEXANDRU ALINA". When I run that code (writing the PicturePath) it displays just "ALEXANDRU".

Comment: What do you mean by "it only takes the first string"? A short but complete program, with sample input, expected output and actual output, would make this *much* clearer.

Comment: Edited my question. Hopefully it is clear now

Comment: Not really - we don't know how you're displaying it, or anything like that. `Directory.GetFiles()` *will* give full filenames, including spaces...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for:

```
string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\uploads");

foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
{
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fileName);
    if (fi.Name.Equals(name, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) PicturePath = fileName;
}
```

What you're attempting to do is find the target file name within the whole path, but the method you're using could produce errors (what if the `name` is contained within part of the folder path?).  By using the `System.FileInfo` class and its `Name` property, which is the *file name only* (not the full file path which includes the containing folder path), you won't be needlessly searching any part of the folder path.

Comment: But what if I want to get the entire fileName (including the .extenstion) and not take the path.

Comment: @RaduStanescu -- the `Name` property includes the extension.

Comment: I managed to do it but instead of that if you described I used if (fi.Name.ToString().Contains(name)) PicturePath = fileName.
It seems to work well. Thanks